# ELK Watcher alert based on percentage of 2 queries in a time range

Tags: elastic-stack

We are switching from splunk to elk and in splunk we created alerts that are based on the percentage derived from the results of 2 queries.

Let's assume that our logging outputs a "complete" message every time the process has completed, and it also outputs an "error" message when an error occurs.  I want to query within a time range for those two messages and if the errors are greater than X% then create an alert.

I have been googling for this for a while but have not found anything.  Any help would be great!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The idea of this is to create one query, and break the result up into separate buckets, in which you could use statistical analysis on the result, using painless.

```
{
  "trigger": ...,
   "input": {
    "search": {
       "request": {
         "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
         "indices": [
          ...
        ],
        "types": [],
         "body": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "Successful",
                    "default_field": "message"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "Failed",
                    "default_field": "message"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "messages": {
              "filters": {
                "other_bucket_key": "successful_requests",
                "filters": {
                  "failed_requests": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "query": {
                            "query_message": "Failed",
                            "default_field:"message"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "script": {
      "source": "return ctx.payload.aggregations.messages.buckets.failed_request.doc_count/ctx.payload.aggregations.messages.buckets.successful_request.doc_count > ctx.metadata.thresholdPercent",
      "lang": "painless"
    }
  },
  "actions": ...
  },
  "metadata": {
    "thresholdPercent": 0.5
  }
}
```

In this example, you search for "Failed OR Successful", then split this result into 2 buckets.  One of these buckets is implicit, while the "failed_request" bucket gets all of the results matching the "Failed" query.  In the condition, you can use painless, and determine if the doc count, over successful requests exceeds a set threshold.
filters bucket aggregations documentation can be found: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html